Golomb subsets of $\mathbb{N}$
A set $A\subseteq\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb{N}}\N$ is said to be Golomb if whenever $a<b \in A$ and $a'<b' \in A$ with $(b-a) = (b' - a')$, then $a=a'$ and $b=b'$. If $A\subseteq \N$ is Golomb, we let $\newcommand{\dist}{\text{dist}}\dist(A) = \{b-a:a < b \in A\}$.
Is there a Golomb set $A\subseteq \N$ with $\dist(A) = \N\setminus\{0\}$? If not, is there a Golomb set $A$ with $$\liminf_{n\to\infty}\frac{|\dist(A)\cap\{1,\ldots,n\}|}{n} = 1?$$

Yes, with a straightforward induction.
Let $F$ be a finite Golomb subset. Let $n\ge 1$ be the smallest element not in $\mathrm{dist}(F)$.
Define $F_m=F\cup\{m,m+n\}$. Define $u(F)=F_m$ where $m$ is the smallest number such that $F_m$ is also Golomb. To prove this is well-defined, it is enough to show that there exists $m$ such that $F_m$ is Golomb, and actually that every large enough $m$ works. Indeed, suppose that $m$ is large enough. Take two distinct increasing pairs and show they have distinct distances. If both are in $F$, then it's OK. If one is in $F$ and the other is $(m,m+n)$, it's OK. If one is in $F$ and one is half in $F$, it's OK (provided $m> 2\max(F)$). If both are half in $F$, say $(f_1,m)$, $(f_2,m+n)$, we have $m-f_1=m+n-f_2$, i.e., $f_2-f_1=n$, contradiction.
Hence define $X_0=\emptyset$, $X_{i+1}=u(X_i)$. Then $X=\bigcup_i X_i$ works.
For instance $$X_{15}=\{1,2,5,7,15,22,38,47,65,76,120,132,154,173,$$
$$241,265,327,353,482,510,575,605,786,821,984,$$ $$1023,1151,1198,1382,1430\}.$$
(It's not in OEIS, apparently.)

Why not add it to OEIS then? It surely deserves it!

Sorry I thought I checked it but cannot reproduce it anymore. After ${1,2}$ I obtain ${1,2,4}$. Indeed $\operatorname{dist}({1,2})={1}$, so $n=2$, and for $m=1$ I get ${1,2}\cup{1,3}={1,2,3}$ which is not Golomb, while for $m=2$ I get ${1,2}\cup{2,4}={1,2,4}$ which is Golomb. In this way I obtain ${1,2,4,8,13,21,31,45,66,81,97,144,166,200,225,307,333,416,444,592,625,679,717,935,974,1135,1175,...}$ (which is also not on OEIS)

See also A005282: $a(n)$ is the smallest number $>a(n-1)$ such that ${a(1),...,a(n)}$ is Golomb. It goes $1,2,4,8,13,21,31,45, 66, 81, 97, 123, 148, 182, 204, 252, 290, 361, 401, 475, 565, 593, 662, 775, 822, 916, 970, 1016, 1159, 1312,...$

Interestingly, A005282 does not answer the question, as its $\mathrm{dist}$ omits A080200 - namely, $33, 88, 98, 99, 105, 106, 112, 126, 130, 132, 134, 150, 152, 154, 156,...$

As for A247556, it does answer the question but is constructed in a different way: let $n$ be as above for ${a(1),...,a(k-1)}$. If ${a(1),...,a(k-1),a(k-1)+n}$ is Golomb then one puts $a(k)=a(k-1)+n$. Otherwise one puts $a(k)=a(k-1)+r$ and $a(k+1)=a(k)+n$ where $r$ is the smallest number with ${a(1),...,a(k-1),a(k-1)+r,a(k-1)+r+n}$ Golomb. The result is still different from what I get, it seems to be more economic, as it omits e. g. $1404, 1772, 1820, 2161, 2210, 2514, 2565, 3004, 3059, 3503, 3560, 4006, 4067, 4447, 4514, 5280, 5350, 5677, 5748,...$
